# How would I check if a link has "/-s" in it?

Tags: javascript, regex

I use the following regex: `\^(https?:\/\/)?(www.)?(m\.)?soundcloud\.com\/[^ "]+\/[^ "]+\/(s\-)[^ "]+\g` to check if a soundcloud link is public or private, however it's not working as I've been reading up on regex's for the past 2 hours and still haven't figured it out, both private and public links test `true`

private link: `https://soundcloud.com/user/album` - SHOULDNT MATCH

private link: `https://soundcloud.com/user/album/IX8PBwQLvX8` - SHOULDNT MATCH

public link: `https://soundcloud.com/user/album/s-IX8PBwQLvX8` - SHOULD MATCH

The unique identifier is the `s-` after the last `/` so I want it to check true **ONLY** if there is a `s-` after the last `/`

My reasoning for this regex, please correct me where needed.
`^(https?:\/\/)?(www.)?(m\.)?`: Check if the string starts with `https://` OR `www.` OR `m.`
`soundcloud\.com`: Check if the domain is `soundcloud.com`, duhh
`\/[^ "]+`: Checks for the next `/` with any amount of characters after it that **aint** `space/u200b` or `"`. I use this twice because of the /user and /album routes
`\/(s\-)`: Find the group `s-` after the last `/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For checking that if after the last backslash is an "s-" you can add this `(?=.*\/s-)` in front of your pattern so it becomes to:

`(?=.*\/s-)^(https?:\/\/)?(www.)?(m\.)?soundcloud\.com\/[^ "]+\/[^ "]+\/(s\-)[^ "]+`

Also, you should escape to the dot after the www and as valid links can't contain space you can safely remove space in this part of your pattern `[^ "]` and as you repeat this part two times you can remove the second part and put it in a group and use {2} that checks this pattern repeat two times:

`(?=.*\/s-)^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?(m\.)?soundcloud\.com\/([^"]+\/){2}(s-)[^"]+`

See Regex [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RMj4zz/1)

Comment: Now that's a quick reply, this does exactly what I want it to do! Thanks @Alireza

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
^(https?:\/\/)?((www|m)\.)?soundcloud\.com(\/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)+\/s-[^ "]+\b
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/MLeae7/1)**

Comment: Perfect! This Regex also does what I requested but I'm going to keep @Alizera's answer as the accepted answer just because they explained what edits they made to my original Regex and what the edits mean/do. This looks like a more compact Regex but I'm too inexperienced to find major differences between this Regex and the one in the accepted answer. If I'm missing something and anyone feels like this should be the accepted answer please do reply to this message